# Is there a "Riemann-Stieltjes integral" for discrete 2D functions?

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, discrete-calculus

I was wondering if Riemann-Stieltjes integral still works when both of the functions $f$ and $g$ are discrete and two dimensional? Something like below:
$$\int f(x,y) dg(x,y)$$

By using the parametric formula of the curve I would be able to write $x$ and $y$ in terms of one variable like angle $\alpha$ but I don't know how that would help me solve this integral which is actually a summation on discrete 2D signals. Any Suggestions?

Comment: there are Lebesgue-Stieltjes measures for arbitrary finite number of dimensions so you can see them as a generalization of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks for your reply. Does that Lebesque integral work even if the $f$ and $g$ are not necessarily nondecreasing?

Comment: there is no simple "nondecreasing" concept for space of dimension equal or above to two. Take a look at some textbook or notes in measure theory to clarify your doubts, [here](http://www.math.utah.edu/~li/L-S%20integral.pdf) there is a brief introduction to the specific subject of Lebesgue-Stieltjes measures.